# Rails Nested Joins Condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Sorry I am bad with Joins.

Here is the scenario

I have three models User, Account, Opportunity

Here is how they are associated

User has one account and account has one opportunity

For Example:
I need to find Opportunities with type "New" and have the user of type "Driver"

`Opportunity.joins(account: :user).where(account: {user: {user_type: "Driver"}}).where(type: "New")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with one where as follow

```
Opportunity.joins(account: :user).where('opportunities.type = ? AND users.type = ?','New','Driver')
```

Comment: Just going to add that you were close in your attempt

`Opportunity.joins(account: :user).where(users: {user_type: "Driver"}).where(type: "New")`

When writing the where on an association you have to specify the name of the table, which in most cases is (should be) the plural form.